# Does it make sense to set EXACTLY the same cookie in the response as came in the request?

Tags: http, cookies

I came across code that sets some cookie in the response based on the cookie in the request - usual case.

I was surprised a bit that in some case it sets (with `Set-Cookie` header) exactly the same cookie as came in the response (in the `Cookie` header).

I *assume* that it was made like this for universality, simplicity reasons but I have no contact with the code author so I cannot verify it.

But I started wondering: **does it make practical sense? Are there any cases where this would come useful?**

(At this point I think that it is wrong to do it because it just takes additional processing power to add it and bandwith to transfer the response with a larger header it without any gains.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies may expire in the server after some time. When a server gets a request with an expired cookie, it should return a response with a different value. Cookies can also expire on the client, because the server included an expire date (making it a persistent cookie) or because it didn't have an expiry time and they was removed when the user closed the browser session.

When cookies have an expiry date, the server wants to refresh that date if the user continue using the website. This technique is called sliding expiration, and the server may re-include the request cookie in the response in time to time with a new expiration date.

Now, if what you see is the request cookie being copied verbatim (with the same expiry date) to the response... right, that does not have any benefit.